# Is there expiration date attribute for Apple Identity Pinning?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin

I have pinned hash of public key on iOS app ([like there](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=g9ejcf8y)). On Android there is option to set expiration time:

```
   <pin-set expiration="2022-05-22">
        <!-- Pin for: some.service.net -->
        <pin digest="SHA-256">lBtyN6YfU7Ij0eOfWidaA519gF1QdLP81iismt4FUdA=</pin>
    </pin-set>
```

Is there similar option on iOS [NSPinnedDomains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nspinneddomains)?

Comment: It seems that the public key doesn't have an expiration date , we can use third-party  library to implement certificate pinning(it has expiration date) , please google `Certificate Pinning in iOS` and check the blog .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No currently there is no provision to set `pin-set expiration` or expiry date using `NSPinnedDomains` in `info.plist`**. The reason for this is as mentioned in comment the public key doesn't have an expiration date and also there is no field to add expiry date in info.plist as of now . Here is an image from the official apple docs : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nspinneddomains

[NSPinnedDomains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PFbY.png)

So in native ssl technique provided by Apple there is no field to set expiry date